# Flipping pages effect in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have to do an animation in a WPF project .

That is,one of the windows should  display person's photos like an album,
 where i should be able to flip the pages to see each person's info.

Each page should contain a header Description of person and a Photo below.

I dont have expression blend.

What is the simple way to do this.I am new to animation featues of WPF.So wher should i begin and which control should i use?

Please provide some inputs.Code samples,links etc.

Thansk

SNA

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2006/11/05/flip-page-demo-using-wpf.aspx)

Comment: Here is a direct link to the code http://wpfbookcontrol.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24122